# Copy UITextView to PasteBoard

Tags: clipboard, uipasteboard, pasteboard

I'm trying to copy my "DescriptionLabel" to the Pasteboard. DescriptionLabel is set as a UITextView (I know the name is a little confusing...). Anyway,

```
- (IBAction)copy:(id)sender {

    UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    appPasteBoard.persistent = YES;
    [appPasteBoard setString:@"This text is being copied"];
    }
```

The string in the code is being copied, but I can't manage to get it copying my UITextView/DescriptionLabel. This:

```
[appPasteBoard setString:_DescriptionLabel];
```

is not working.

Do any of you have any clue of what I can do to make it work? Been struggling with this for days...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Anyway, the pasteboard cannot hold *arbitrary* objects. Did you want to `setString:_DescriptionLabel.text` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you are using `setString:` to store UITextView, which is an UIKit control and not NSString, in pasteboard. What you probably mean is to store its text value.

Objective-C does not support implicit conversions like Scala or Swift. Solution is simple, just access the `text` property explicitly:

```
[appPasteBoard setString:_DescriptionLabel.text];
```

I encourage you to look into `UIPasteboard` documentation for details concerning it API: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html